# Error with opencv and tensorflow typeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

when I run the code I get this error. I feel like there is invalid syntax but I am not sure. This is for tensorflow live object detection

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```py
     26         vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
     27             image_np,
---> 28             output_dict['detection_boxes'],
     29             output_dict['detection_classes'],
     30             output_dict['detection_scores'],

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
    all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
    tensor_dict = {}
    for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
        ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
            tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)

    while True:
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Actual detection.
        output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np_expanded, detection_graph)
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            output_dict['detection_boxes'],
            output_dict['detection_classes'],
            output_dict['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
        cv2.imshow('object_detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xff == ord==('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. `output_dict` is set to `None`. This had to have occurred in the line where it is set by `run_inference_for_single_image(image_np_expanded, detection_graph)`, probably because something went wrong in that function or beforehand. If you need more help, you're going to need to provide more information.

Comment: Sai Veeramachaneni, Can you please provide complete code and the dataset you are using (if they can be shared) so that we can try reproducing the issue and work towards resolution. Thanks.